# cannot render the weight

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm working on a website. My client want me to show the weight of product. But the condition is if the weight is less than a Kg, it should show the grams. If it is more than a kg it should show the kg along with fraction point i,e if the weight is 1 kg 350 grams then it should show 1.35 Kg. My code for it goes like this.

```
<?php $_weight = $_product->getweight()?>
<?php if ($_weight >= 1) : ?>
<span><?php echo($_weight)?>Kg<span>
<?php else: ?>
<? $_weight1=($_weight * 1000) ?>
<span><?php echo(round($_weight1))?>grams<span>
<?php endif;?>
<br/>
```

But I don't know how to show the kg with only two fraction numbers. Please help me. I'm a budding developer.

Comment: list some value which u got from `$_weight = $_product->getweight();`

Answer (score 0):

You almost got there - when you use the `round()` function you can specify the decimal precision as the 2nd parameter.

```
<span><?php echo($_weight)?>Kg<span>
```

becomes

```
<span><?php echo(round($_weight,2))?>Kg<span>
```

http://php.net/round

Comment: you might want to check the return value from $_product->getweight() then the value might be getting rounded before returning from that method

Comment: num: Thanks You for your kind guidance.

Answer (score 0):

`<? $_weight1=($_weight * 1000) ?>` line replace with `<?php $_weight1=($_weight * 1000) ?>` and try...

```
<?php $_weight = $_product->getweight(); ?>
<?php if ($_weight >= 1) { ?>
<span><?php echo round($_weight,2); ?>Kg<span>
<?php }else{ ?>
<?php $_weight1= round($_weight * 1000); ?>
<span><?php echo $_weight1; ?>grams<span>
<?php } ?>
<br/>
```